# Excel to PowerPoint VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to paste few cells from Excel to a slide in PowerPoint, using an ActiveX CheckBox in Excel as control. There is no problem of transferring one slide to my designated PowerPoint Presentation, but the problem appears when I ticked more than one box.

So what I do is basically making a temporary template presentation, and when I click on another button called the "Launch" button, it will be pasted to my designated presentation. This is my code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PP.Presentations.Open("(my temporary filename)")
Dim iCheckCount As Integer
iCheckCount = 0
Dim obj As OLEObject

    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If obj.Object.Value = True Then iCheckCount = iCheckCount + 1

            Next


If iCheckCount = 1 Then

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(1)


With PPSlide
.Shapes("Textfeld 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 4").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 5").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 6").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Text
End With
PPPres.Slides(1).Copy

Else
If iCheckCount > 1 Then
    PPPres.Slides.Paste
    PPPres.Slides(2).Copy

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(1)
With PPSlide
.Shapes("Textfeld 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("G3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 4").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 5").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Text
.Shapes("Textfeld 6").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Text
End With

End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

I know that it won't work for more than 2 boxes (copied to designated Presentation). So my questions are:

1) How can you copy more than 1 Slide at once? I´ve tried

```
For i = 1 to PPPres.Slides.Count
PPPres.Slides.Item(i).Copy
Next i
```

but it won't work.

2) I found an if code for every ticked ActiveX CheckBox I have. But the problem is, how can I mention all the Sub for CheckBox_Click and ask the program to do it? The names of the Sub are Box1, Box2, Box3,...,Box46.

I know that my questions are really messy and I'm not explaining it very well since I am also new to VBA. Don't hesitate to ask me if you want to know more about my code.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You may use e.g:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 2, 3)).Duplicate
' Or
For i = 1 to PPPres.Slides.Count
    PPPres.Slides.Item(i).Duplicate
Next i
```